# How to get a unique word from file appearing in start of every line using shell script

Tags: shell

I have a text file having fields with delimited by '|' symbol. I want to get the distinct fields from start of lines in file.

For example, say my file data is like :

```
FEEDS TEST|mke-tpefdrt3a|5|32|Serial1/0|44210000
NEW FEEDS|mke-tpefdrt3a|5|32|E1_10.10.10.01
NEW FEEDS|mke-tpefdrt3a|5|32|Serial1/0|44210000
NEW FEEDS|mke-tpefdrt3a.gcsc.com|5|32|Serial1/0
REPORT|mke-tpefdrt3a|5|32|Serial1/0|44210000|
```

I want output like this:

```
FEEDS TEST
NEW FEEDS
NEW FEEDS
```

Comment: Why 5 input lines and just 3 in the output? In case you want unique, I understand it should be `FEEDS TEST`, `NEW FEEDS`, `REPORT`.

Comment: your question is not clear. you want distinct output and your output shows 'NEWS FEED' twice. How come??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This awk

```
$ awk -F\| '!a[$1]++{print $1}' infile
```

Will give you

```
FEEDS TEST
NEW FEEDS
REPORT
```

Comment: That's the solution! Well done, I thought about `cut -d'|' -f1 | sort | uniq` but this is pretty more straight forward.